# Unix: copy batch of files (filenames in text file) to another directory

Tags: unix, copy

I have a text-file with many filenames in a single column (~4,000 lines) and a directory with ~13,000 files (including the ~4,000 files in the text-file). How do I copy only the ~4,000 files in the text-file to another directory?

Comment: is there any pattern to identify these "text-file"s.. if so then we can use a combination of find and xrgs with copy command.

Comment: No, not really... There are all totally different filenames in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should make it:

```
while read file
do
   file=$(echo $file | tr -d '\\r')
   cp dir/$file another_dir/
done < your_file
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately it doesn't quite work yet... I get the message "cp: cannot stat `TN-Buccal_9.CEL.gz\r': No such file or directory" about 4000 times (TN-Buccal_9.CEL.gz is one of the filenames in the text-file).

Comment: @Abdel MMm it is not finding your files. Check the `dir`. Also, you can delete `dir` if you are running the code in the dir where these files are.

Comment: It still doesn't work and I'm quite sure the files are there... Could it have to do with the \r in the error message unix gives me? Doesn't that mean new line? Can I let him ignore the \r (newline) at the end of each filename in some way?

Comment: Yes @Abdel , it must be this: as the file it is looking for has an extra `\r`, it does not detect it. See my updated answer, in which I remove this character.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash you can also use:

```
for f in `cat file` ; do cp $f destination ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work....it depends on how long the filenames are.

```
cp `cat text-file` target_directory
```